# Given two dataframes with grouped items and another with equivalent groups, can I create a dataframe with all pairs of units from matching groups?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe `df1`:

```
   df1_unit   base_unit
0     x         x
1     y         x
2     z         z
3     t         z
4     u         z
```

and another called `df2`:

```
   df2_unit   base_unit
0     a         b
1     b         b
2     c         c
3     d         e
4     e         e
```

and yet another dataframe `df_eq` that gives the equivalence between groups:

```
   df1_unit   df2_unit
0     x         b
1     z         e
```

In case of `df1`, the `base_unit` is basically the `df1_unit` that acts as a parent unit for all the units in a group. i.e. `x` is the base unit with which the `x`, `y`, `z` units are identified as a group. Similarly for `df2`.

I'm trying to generate a dataframe with all possible pairs of items from equivalent groups, *but without the pairs in the `df_eq` dataframe (this is a restriction we impose)*. In this case, the unrestricted output would be:

```
   df1_unit   df2_unit
0     x         a
1     x         b       (shouldn't be included)
2     y         a
3     y         b
4     z         d
5     z         e       (shouldn't be included)
6     t         d
7     t         e
8     u         d
9     u         e
```

and the **desired, restricted output would be**:

```
   df1_unit   df2_unit
0     x         a
1     y         a
2     y         b
3     z         d
4     t         d
5     t         e
6     u         d
7     u         e
```

I'm having difficulty in generating even the unrestricted output without resorting to ridiculous brute force methods. Is there an efficient way to achieve the desired output?

EDIT: I've made some headway using the following code:

```
temp = dfeq.rename(columns={'df2u':'base_unit'}).merge(df2, on='base_unit', how='left')
temp = temp[['df1u', 'df2u']]
out = temp.rename(columns={'df1u':'base_unit'}).merge(df1, on='base_unit', how='left')
out = out[['df1u', 'df2u']]
```

Does this seem correct? Also, I'm not sure about how to remove the rows in `out` that are also present in `dfeq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following approach:

1. We are going to map `base_unit` column in `df1`, taking into account the data in `df_eq`, for that we are going to use [`to_dict(orient='split')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html?highlight=to_dict#pandas.DataFrame.to_dict) to build a dictionary which will be used by [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html?highlight=map#pandas.Series.map) method.

   ```
   map_base_unit_df2 = dict(df_eq.to_dict(orient='split')['data']) 
   df1['base_unit'] = df1['base_unit'].map(map_base_unit_df2)
   ```
2. We are going to build `df_unrestricted` using [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge) selecting only the columns matter for us.

   ```
   df_unrestricted = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='base_unit')[['df1_unit', 'df2_unit']]
   ```
3. Finally, adding the final restriction, I mean, we are going to drop the records present in `df_eq`, using [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.DataFrame.merge) + [`drop_duplicates(keep=False)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html?highlight=drop_duplicate) + [`reset_index(drop=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

   ```
   df_output = pd.concat([df_unrestricted, df_eq]).drop_duplicates(keep=False).reset_index(drop=True)
   ```

***Full code:***

```
map_base_unit_df2 = dict(df_eq.to_dict(orient='split')['data']) 
df1['base_unit'] = df1['base_unit'].map(map_base_unit_df2)
df_unrestricted = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='base_unit')[['df1_unit', 'df2_unit']]
df_output = pd.concat([df_unrestricted, df_eq]).drop_duplicates(keep=False).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_output)
```

Output:

```
   df1_unit df2_unit
0      x       a
1      y       a
2      y       b
3      z       d
4      t       d
5      t       e
6      u       d
7      u       e
```